# attaching an event handler to dropdown options html that is loaded via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been reading about his and I realize that I need a delegated event handler.

EDIT: What I am trying to do is this: When a person picks a new value, I would like an event fired that fills in a list of options for an adjacent dropdown box. At this point, if an alert fired I would know that it works. However, that is not happening. what I would like is for an event to be fired when a new option is chosen

**My event handler:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#DDgrade').on("change", ".oDDclass", function() {
 var originatingid = jQuery(this).attr("id");
 var grade =    $("#DDgrade :selected").text();
alert('grade= '+grade);
return;
  }); 
});
```

**Code that creates the dropdown:**

```
<select name="DDgrade" id="DDgrade" onChange="$('#theotherdropdowns').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});" style="width:130px;height:30px;margin-bottom:5px;">
<option value="Grade">Grade</option>

<?php
    $mysqli1 = connecttomydatabase();
    $query2="
    SELECT grade 
    FROM a10daydefaults 
    ;";

    $stmt = $mysqli1->prepare($query2) ; echo $stmt->error ;
    //var_dump($mysqli1->error);
    if ( $stmt->execute() ) {;} else{ printf("Query error: %s", $stmt->error); } 
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($theresult);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $theresult ."<br>";
        echo "<option value='$theresult' class='oDDclass'>$theresult</option>";
    }           
    $stmt->free;
    $stmt->close;
?>          
</select>
```

I have read about this, and I thought that I was doing it correctly but it does not work.

Comment: whats is "DDgrade"..!

Comment: it's the <select> ID "i guess"

Comment: You are correct yes. I'll adjust the question to include that.

Comment: have you tried using 'mouseclick' as the event instead of 'change' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no change event for an `option` element only for the `select` element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change

**Update** if the select element is not dynamically added to the page there is no need for event delegation, you can do the following

```
$('#DDgrade').change(function(){
     var grade =    $("#DDgrade :selected").text();
     alert('grade= '+grade);
});
```

See it in action, with the option of dynamicaly added option elements: http://jsfiddle.net/nNK9y/

If you were dynamically adding the **select** element to the page, then you'd need delegation.

Comment: So, should I use $('#DDgrade').on("change", "option.oDDclass", function() ? I did just try that and it did not work. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Do you want something to happen when an option is selected? `$('#DDgrade').on("change", "option.oDDclass", function()` is attempting to atatch a change event to an option, which will do nothing.

Comment: I must not understand this then. It took me a while to determine that I needed a delegated event handler. Now that I know this, I've tried to set the code but I must be doing something wrong. What I am trying to do is this: When a person picks a new value, I would like an event fired that fills in a list of options for an adjacent dropdown box. At this point, if an alert fired I would know that it works. However, that is not happening. what I would like is for an event to be fired when a new option is chosen.

Comment: OK, you need to put the event handler on the `Select`. For now I will assume that this is not dynamicaly added to the page via ajax. Only the options. Updating answer shortly.

Comment: Yes, thank you Jon P, you are correct. The selects are there and also the very first option in each dropdown. The HTML validator required that. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this works if put in a $(document).ready. That is very similar to what I at one point already had. I was juggling the classes/ids wrong. Thank you for your input!